# how add facet to pysolr query

Tags: solr, python-2.7, pysolr

I am new to solr,am using pysolr, I have a very basic question.

```
How can I add a facet to the pysolr query?
my solr query is: ip:8983/solr....q=...&facet=on&facet.field=xyz
```

its working in browser as I wish.

I want to know how can I implement it  in my following code,

> what the syntax to add facet in pysolr(facet=on&facet.field=xyz )

**

```
solrquery = "(.................. )" 
 solr.search([solrquery],)
```

**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
solrquery = "(.................. )" 
solr.search([solrquery],facet = 'on' ,** {'facet.field' : ['fieldname']})
```